# Server changes didn't get reflected after yarn dev in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I have a `nextjs` custom server file, but whatever the changes I make, after doing build and running, it doesn't reflect at all in terminal. For example, in the below code:

```js
    const app: any = next({ dev })
    app.prepare().then(() => {
      const server = express();
      server.get(`*`, (req: any, res: any) => {
        console.log("Test");
        // Trying to call the function
      })

      server.get(`/`, (req: any, res: any) => {
        console.log("Test empty");
      })
      server.get(`/getFile`, (req: any, res: any) => {
        console.log("Test file url empty");
      })
```

Above 3 sets of api routes didn't get executed either.

`package.json`:

```json
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 next dev"
```

I'm trying to do `yarn dev` and not able to see any new changes or logs getting reflected in terminal. I'm new to `Nextjs` and not sure. Can anyone please suggest me to resolve it?

Comment: Hi there, your code looks like an express.js app instead of next.js api route.

Comment: @OxKevin Hi Kevin, With next js they have customized server with nodejs.

Comment: Ok, got it. Then, you will have to add `server.listen(3000, () => {});` too at the end of your code inside `app.prepare()` block.

Comment: @0xKevin Listening to the server is already there, but still if we make any changes after restarting its not reflecting.

Comment: Do you mean with "hot reloading" when you make changes? Or, any changes that you make doesn't even work at all?

Comment: @0xKevin Any changes that Im making doesnt even work at all

Comment: Ok, got it. I will post an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the contexts and codes that you shared, it's not enough to verify what is the exact reason of the issue, but here are some considerations that you may have to check in.

1. In your `package.json` file, you've specified a command for running
   `Next.js` in development mode without using a custom server script:

   ```
   "dev": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 next dev"
   ```

   This command runs the standard `Next.js` development server and does
   not involve your custom server file (e.g., a file where you define
   the Express server). To use your custom server during development,
   you need to modify this script to run your custom server file. If
   your custom server file is named `server.js`, you would update the
   script like this:

   ```
   "dev": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 node server.js"
   ```

   or simply test with `"dev": "node server.js"` if you're unsure your `cross-env` configuration has been set up correctly.

   To enable hot-reloading on your server file, you can install and use
   `nodemon`:

   ```
   "dev": "cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 nodemon server.js"
   ```

   I'd recommend trying with `"dev": "nodemon server.js"` first.
2. In the code snippet you provided, there's a potential issue with the
   order of route definitions. Express routes are evaluated in the
   order they're defined, so specific routes should come before more
   general ones. The catch-all route `*` will match all incoming
   requests, potentially preventing more specific routes like `/` and
   `/getFile` from being reached. So, consider reordering your routes
   properly. Below is the revised version of your code:

   ```
   import express from 'express';
   import next from 'next';

   const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
   const app = next({ dev });
   const handle = app.getRequestHandler(); // Next.js handler

   app.prepare().then(() => {
     const server = express();

     server.get('/getFile', (req, res) => {
       console.log("getFile route has been reached.");
       res.send("Response from the getFile route.");
     });

     server.get('/', (req, res) => {
       console.log("root route has been reached.");
       res.send("Response from the root route.");
     });

     // Catch-all route for Next.js routes
     server.get('*', (req, res) => {
       console.log("All other routes here!");
       return handle(req, res); // Hand off to Next.js's request handler
     });

     server.listen(3000, () => {
       console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
     });
   });
   ```

I hope this could resolve your issue. If not, I'd like you to provide more context and code snippets so I can have better understanding of your issue.